# Discord.py: Slash command interaction error

Tags: python, discord.py

*I am using Pycord*

The code below is the slash command I am using.

```
class slashcommands(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
    
    @commands.slash_command(
        guild_ids = testingservers,
        name = "prefix", 
        description = "check which prefix on this server")
    async def prefix(self, ctx):
        with open('Source\\prefixes\\prefixs.json', 'r') as f:
            prefixes = json.load(f)

        try: prefix = prefixes[str(ctx.guild.id)]
        except KeyError:
            prefix = "_"

        await ctx.respond(f"This Server prefix is : ``{prefix}``")
```

Below is an error when using the slash command above.

```
Ignoring exception in on_interaction
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\bot.py", line 738, in process_application_commands
    command = self._application_commands[interaction.data["id"]]
KeyError: '969961755574947870'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 352, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\bot.py", line 1048, in on_interaction
    await self.process_application_commands(interaction)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\bot.py", line 755, in process_application_commands
    await self.sync_commands(unregister_guilds=[guild_id])
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\bot.py", line 693, in sync_commands
    await self.http.bulk_upsert_command_permissions(
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 338, in request
    raise HTTPException(response, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 405 Method Not Allowed (error code: 0): 405: Method Not Allowed
```

Idk why causes that.
Its worked before.

Please tell me how to fix that.

Comment: Ever tried to indent the code in the right way? (`try: prefix = prefixes[str(ctx.guild.id)]` does not look correct). You are also getting a `KeyError` which tells you a lot...

Comment: Do you have the permissions to run slash commands? Check that your bot has application.commands permission.